# How to remove active class of previously selected list item on selecting new one in angular

Tags: css, angular

I want to remove the active class of list item which I had set intentionally active so when the page load I want this list item to remain active using routerLinkActive="active". I want to disable this active class when I select the other items of list in angular

I tried using ngClass but didn't worked as expected. How can this be done without using jquery?

```
<ul class="nav"> 
       <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem == menuItem}" (click)="listClick($event, menuItem)">
         <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]">
         <p>{{ menuItem.title }}</p>
        </a>
       </li>
     </ul>

declare interface RouteInfo {
  path: String,
  title: String,
  class: String
}
export const ROUTES: RouteInfo[] = [
  { path: '', title: 'Dashboard', class: '' },
  { path: '/vessel', title: 'Vessel Details', class: '' },
  { path: '/arrival', title: 'Arrival Details', class: ''},
  { path: '/stock', title: 'StockYard', class: ''},
  { path: '/cargo', title: 'Cargo Details', class: '' },
  { path: '/other', title: 'Others', class: ''}

];

menuItems: any[];
  selectedItem= false;

listClick(event, newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    this.selectedItem = !this.selectedItem;

  }
```

The intentionally setted active class should be disabled when other list items are clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what your trying to do now. You shouldn't need to use ngClass or the click event. Angular will check to see if the active route matches the routerLink path. If it does, the class specified in ActiveRouterLink is added.

It's hard to solve your issue without knowing what you are seeing but try adding [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true} to the li element.